# Import plain text file in to JSON via JQ

Tags: json, text, import, jq

I have two files:

id_rsa

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and id_rsa.pub

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA...
```

Using JQ, how can import them into a json file like:

```
{
  "pem": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "pub": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA..."
}
```

I have tried a couple, but it's not working:

```
jq --null-input --argfile pem id_rsa --argfile pub id_rsa.pub '.pem=$pem | .pub=$pub'
jq: Bad JSON in --argfile pem id_rsa: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 11
```

Comment: Did either of the answers below work? If so you should provide feedback by accepting/upvoting the desired one

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your jq supports the `--rawfile` command-line option (as does jq 1.6), the simplest would be to use it, e.g.:

```
jq -Rs --rawfile pub id_rsa.pub '{pem: ., pub: $pub}' id_rsa
```

The `-R` flag (aka `--raw-input`) tells jq not to parse the input as JSON. Each line of text is passed directly to the filter as a string.

The `-s` flag (aka `--slurp`) tells jq to read the entire incoming stream at one time. Combined with `-R` this pulls the entire file into a single variable.

### Without --rawfile

```
jq -Rs --argfile pub <(jq -R '{pub: .}' id_rsa.pub) '{pem: .} + $pub' id_rsa
```

### Trailing newlines

If you want to ensure there is no trailing `\n` at the end of the strings, then you could add calls to `sub("\n$";"")` as warranted.